# How to prevent certain files from being copied to a new branch without actually deleting them in git

Tags: git

Let's say I have a `branchA` that contains a `.github/workflows/ci-cd.yml` file. This branch runs a GitHub Actions whenever code gets pushed to this.

Now, I need to create a new branch `branchB` from `branchA`, but I don't want it to contain the `.github/workflows/ci-cd.yml` file because this branch shouldn't run any GitHub Actions.

Afterwards, I will eventually merge `branchB` back into `branchA`, triggering the GitHub Actions. But everytime I merge a branch without the `yml` file, `branchA`'s `yml` file also gets deleted.

Comment: there is a way to say, in the ci-cd.yml file, that an action should only be triggered on certain branches or tags. check the documentation

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick would be that right after branching from `BranchA`, you could create a commit containing the deletion of `.github/workflows/ci-cd.yml`, then continue adding changes to `branchB`and right before merging it back, revert the first commit with `git revert`.

You could also, instead of doing a `git revert`, do an interactive rebase on `BranchB` (`git rebase -i`) to *drop* the first commit. The result will be as is you had never deleted the yml file which is cleaner, in my opinion, than having a commit that deletes the yml file and another one that reverts that.